# My chat server is responding to the correct thread/client but send button must be clicked equal to the number of clients

Tags: java

I have made a chat server using socket that can handle multiple clients and can reply to individual clients..the client can chat only with the server..But as the number client increases, the server has to click send button as same as the client's number.....i.e; one click to reply when there is only one client connected...click twice when there is two clients and so on..... how can i solve it???
The server is like:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class NewClass1{

 private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
 static Socket clientSocket = null;

         private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
      private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];
    private static LinkedHashMap<String, clientThread> hm = new LinkedHashMap<String, clientThread>();
    public static HashMap<String, clientThread> getinfo(){
    return hm;
    }
      public static void main(String args[]) {

          int portNumber = 22222;
        if (args.length < 1) {
          System.out.println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatServerSync <portNumber>\n"
              + "Now using port number=" + portNumber);
        } else {
          portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
        }


        try {
          serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }


        while (true) {
          try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
              if (threads[i] == null) {
                (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
                System.out.println("hiiiiiiiiiii");
                break;
              }
            }
            if (i == maxClientsCount) {
              PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
              os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
              os.close();
              clientSocket.close();
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class clientThread extends Thread {

      static String clientName = null;
      private BufferedReader br=null;
      private DataInputStream is = null;
      private PrintStream os = null;
      private static Socket clientSocket = null;
      private final clientThread[] threads;
      private int maxClientsCount;
    private static HashMap<String, clientThread> hm = new HashMap<>();
      public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.threads = threads;
        maxClientsCount = threads.length;
     this.hm=NewClass1.getinfo();
      }

      public void run() {
        final int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
        final clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

        try {

            br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.flush();
          String name;
          while (true) {
            os.println("Enter your name.");
            name = is.readLine().trim();
            if (name.indexOf('@') == -1) {
              break;
            } else {
              os.println("The name should not contain '@' character.");
            }
          }



            System.out.println("\n"+name+" has joined");


          os.println("Welcome " + name
              + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
          synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
              if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
                  clientName = "@"+name;
                     hm.put(clientName, this);
                break;
                      } 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
              if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
                threads[i].os.println("*** A new user " + clientName
                    + " entered the chat room !!! ***");
              }
            }
          }

            new Thread(new New()).start();




                             while(true){
                            String line=br.readLine();
                                 if (line.startsWith("@")) {
                  String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
              if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) {
                words[1] = words[1].trim();
               if (!words[1].isEmpty()) {

                   for(Map.Entry<String,clientThread> e:hm.entrySet()){
                   if(words[0].equals(e.getKey())){ 

                          clientThread get=e.getValue();
                           get.os.println("Server:\t" + words[1]);
                            os.flush();
                           System.out.println("\nServer to "+e.getKey()+":\t"+words[1]);

                            break;   
                      }
                   else{
                   continue;
                   }
                   }
               }}}

                     else {           System.out.println("Please type @recipent's name.");
               }}


        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
    }
    class New extends Thread{
        public void run(){
       DataInputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new DataInputStream(NewClass1.clientSocket.getInputStream());
                String lin=null;
                while((lin=is.readLine())!=null)
                        {   
                            //lin=is.readLine();
                            System.out.println(clientThread.clientName+": "+lin);

                        }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(New.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(New.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

    }
    }
```

The client is like:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class NewClass implements Runnable {

  // The client socket
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  // The output stream
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  // The input stream
  private static DataInputStream is = null;

  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // The default port.
    int portNumber = 22222;
    // The default host.
    String host = "localhost";

    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.out
          .println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatClient <host> <portNumber>\n"
              + "Now using host=" + host + ", portNumber=" + portNumber);
    } else {
      host = args[0];
      portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
     */
    try {
      clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }

    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
     * socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber.
     */
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
      try {

        /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
        new Thread(new NewClass()).start();
        while (!closed) {
            String msg=inputLine.readLine();
          os.println(msg.trim());
          os.flush();
            System.out.println("\nClient: \t"+msg);
        }
        /*
         * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
         */
        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create a thread to read from the server. (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
   */
  public void run() {
    /*
     * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
     * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
     */
    String responseLine;
    try {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("\n"+responseLine);
        if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1)
          break;
      }
      closed = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your code, sounds like you've got a loop in the wrong place or one missing?

Comment: I have added the server module alongside thread.......@BretC

Comment: Does this compile? At the moment, in my IDE, I get an error on the `System.out.println("hellllooooooooooo");` line saying that this code is unreachable

Comment: i hav again edited the post..now u can try new one

Comment: Here the server should reply to individual clients like this::   @clientname message.............@BretC

Comment: @BretC did u find my mistake??

Comment: Can anyone solve this problem??? @BretC ????

Comment: Why is this static in the clientThread class - `private static Socket clientSocket = null;`

Comment: instead of relying on static fields, try passing instances of Sockets and things to your handler classes (like "clientThread" and "New") in the constructor